# Access Time Series Insights Gen2 from Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity, azure-timeseries-insights

Access to Time Series Insights is handled by acquiring an access token for a Application in Azure Active Directory which is being given access to time series insights according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-authentication-and-authorization).

In a scenario where my application is running in Azure App Service, is it possible to skip the step of creating a application in AD and use the Managed Identity of App Service to access Time Series Insights this way? How can i obtain the Access Token in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can absolutely do that. In that case, you'd follow the Azure AD guidance on how to acquire tokens for resources as an MSI. Please see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#using-the-rest-protocol). The resource would be `https://api.timeseries.azure.com/` and one of the optional properties is required. Note that you'd also have to first grant the MSI either the reader or contributor role for your TSI environment.